# How to create a many-to-many relationship variable and increase code usability?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a common utility for file transfer, from source to destination. The arguments are separated into `dir` and `filename`, which is the result of `os.path.dirname(some_file)` and `os.path.basename(some_file)`, respectively. The destination filename is the same as the source filename by default if not specified.

I have created a script that at least is working perfectly well with the specific requirements in my first project. But as you can notice, the `get_src_des` method is very repetitive that I want to improve the code re-usability out from the nasty `if`...`elif`... statement. Anyone has better idea to rewrite this method?

```
class FileTransfer:

    def __init__(self, ftp_dir, local_dir, ftp_filename=None, local_filename=None):
        self.ftp_dir = ftp_dir
        self.ftp_filename = ftp_filename
        self.local_dir = local_dir
        self.local_filename = local_filename

        self.ftp_dict = self.get_group(ftp_dir, ftp_filename)
        self.local_dict = self.get_group(local_dir, local_filename)

    @staticmethod
    def get_group(dir, filename):
        group = {
            "dir": dir,
            "filename": filename,
        }
        return group

    def get_src_des(self, src):
        if src == "ftp":
            dict_src = self.ftp_dict
            dict_des = self.local_dict
        elif src == "local":
            dict_src = self.local_dict
            dict_des = self.ftp_dict
        else:
            dict_src = None
            dict_des = None

        return dict_src, dict_des

    # other methods, such as download_from_src_to_des, upload_from_src_to_des, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that that this could be done with a dictionary, as @Yakov Dan's answer suggests, but I would code it as shown below, which doesn't require any other changes to the `class` and is more dynamic.

The `get_group()` method could be written more concisely, as indicated.

```
class FileTransfer:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_group(dir, filename):
        return dict(dir=dir, filename=filename)

    def get_src_des(self, src):
        return {
            'ftp': (self.ftp_dict, self.local_dict),
            'local': (self.local_dict, self.ftp_dict)
        }.get(src, (None, None))
```

Comment: This version of `get_src_des` creates the dict each time. Creating it once in `__init__` is more efficient.

Comment: @cco: True, but creating it on-the-fly means that it uses the current values of the instance's attributes, not what they were when it was created. It also doesn't require modifying any other parts of the class—so unless doing it dynamically as show is causing a significant slow-down—so it sounds to me like your suggestion is a [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is classic use case for a dictionary.

You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
class FileTransfer:

    def __init__(self, ftp_dir, local_dir, ftp_filename=None, local_filename=None):
        self.ftp_dir = ftp_dir
        self.ftp_filename = ftp_filename
        self.local_dir = local_dir
        self.local_filename = local_filename

        self.ftp_dict = self.get_group(ftp_dir, ftp_filename)
        self.local_dict = self.get_group(local_dir, local_filename)
        self.param_dict = {
            'ftp':(self.ftp_dict,self.local_dict),
            'local' : (self.local_dict,self.ftp_dict)
        }

    @staticmethod
    def get_group(dir, filename):
        group = {
            "dir": dir,
            "filename": filename,
        }
        return group

    def get_src_des(self, src):
        if src in param_dict:
           return param_dict[src]

        else:
          return (None,None)
```

Next time, instead of adding another elif statement, you just add another entry in your `param_dict`